# In colab, reverse a list then return a NoneType

Tags: python

I have a list M, containing 3 numpy arrays.
when I wrote M = M.reverse(), then M became the noneType.
Why this happens? To me the result should be a reversed list.

Thanks

Comment: `reverse` is an in place operation, which means it modify the list in-place and return `None`

Comment: What @AbdulNiyasPM is saying is that to reverse M, you need to do `M.reverse()` instead of `M = M.reverse()` as it is an in place operation. It does not return any value that's why on assignment you get M as `NoneType`

Answer (score -2):

Lists belong to the collection data types in Python and are implemented as objects with a set of collection methods, where not all methods return a value.

Specifically `.reverse()` is a method that directly modifies the list, but does not return a value, therefore to access the reversed list, you just use the variable it is assigned to (`M` in your case).